# Why does the address of _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ depend on which function takes it?

Tags: c++, linker, position-independent-code

I would like to take and use the address of `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_`. My expectation is that the address of this symbol does not change over the course of a program.

However, the value of its address seems to depend on which function takes it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

extern void* _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_;

void* foo()
{
  return (void*)&_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_;
}

void* bar()
{
  return (void*)&_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_;
}

void* baz()
{
  return (void*)&_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "foo(): " << foo() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "bar(): " << bar() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "baz(): " << baz() << std::endl;

  assert(foo() == bar());
  assert(foo() == baz());
  assert(bar() == baz());

  return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
$ clang global_offset_table_repro.cpp -lstdc++
$ ./a.out 
foo(): 0x20076c
bar(): 0x20075c
baz(): 0x20074c
a.out: global_offset_table_repro.cpp:27: int main(): Assertion `foo() == bar()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Compiling with `-fPIC` produces a consistent result:

```
$ clang global_offset_table_repro.cpp -lstdc++ -fPIC
jhoberock@jhoberock-dt:~/dev/git/oz$ ./a.out 
foo(): 0x601000
bar(): 0x601000
baz(): 0x601000
```

As does compiling with `g++`:

```
$ g++ global_offset_table_repro.cpp -lstdc++
$ ./a.out 
foo(): 0x555eab725f80
bar(): 0x555eab725f80
baz(): 0x555eab725f80
```

Compiler details:

```
$ clang --version ; echo ; g++ --version
clang version 4.0.1-6 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

g++ (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2) 7.2.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Is the `clang` behavior expected?

Comment: Is there a global offset table for non position independent code? I can't find documentation for this symbol in info ld. Do you know where this is documented?

Comment: You aren't taking the value of _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_, you are taking the address of a location which contains the value.  Clang is declaring 3 different locations and GCC is declaring 1.

Comment: I do not think it is specified anywhere that address of GOT, as resolved by the linker, would be consistent across program execution.